# How to use polygon() to shade below a probability density curve

Tags: r, plot

I'm having trouble getting `polygon()` to shade **below** the distribution all the way to the x-axis. It seems to shade above the exponential distribution to a `y=-x` line. Here is where what I have so far:

```
x <- seq(0,50,0.01)
y <- dexp(seq(0,50,0.01),rate=0.11)
plot(x, y, type="l", col=col2rgb("yellow",0.5), xaxs="i", yaxs="i", ylim=c(0,0.15))
polygon(x, y ,border=NA,col=col2rgb("yellow",0.5))
```

[image: bad shade]

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution is simple, by **adding `(0,0)` to the vertices of the polygon**. See below:

```
x <- seq(0,50,0.01)
y <- dexp(seq(0,50,0.01),rate=0.11)
plot(x, y, type="l", col=col2rgb("yellow",0.5), xaxs="i", yaxs="i", ylim=c(0,0.15))
polygon(c(0, x), c(0, y), border=NA, col=col2rgb("yellow",0.5))
```

[image: shade]

---

**How `polygon()` works**

`polygon()` will **line up all vertices in order**. The problem of your original code is that the origin `(0, 0)` is not one of the vertices, so it will not be part of the polygon. You can also consider the following toy example:

```
x0 <- c(0, 0.5, 1.5)
y0 <- c(1.5, 0.5, 0)
## triangle, with three vertices
plot(x0, y0, pch = ".")
polygon(x0, y0, col = "red", border = NA)
## area under triangle, four vertices
polygon(c(0, x0), c(0, y0), col = "yellow", border = NA)
```

[image: toy example]